# Porque no me aparece el navigation item?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4

EStoy aprendiendo a programar en IOS swift xcode 10, y anadi un navigation controller y obviamente el viewcontroller que ya esta por defecto como pueden ver en la imagen solo tengo el navigation item y un scrollview , pero al ejecutar la app no me muestra el menu y como pueden ver en el inspector se esta tickeado el shows navigation bar y aun asi no se muestra alguna solucion ? muchas gracias. o hay q hacerle algo mas?

[image: Show NavigationBar Actived]

[image: Presigning]

[image: The result]

El error en constraint es porque se necesita el tamano de los contenidos pero no creo que sea por eso , muchas gracias.

Comment: Yo ni idea, pero alguien con conocimientos podra ayudarte.

Comment: pon el codigo del didLoad del viewcontroller puede que lo estes ocultando ahi. o lo estes poniendo transparente por eso no se debe ver